Modem Manager can't find Mobile Broadband
I have Debian 11 running on a computer. I have a ZTE MF79U dongle with a vodafone simcard in it.
I plug it in and then I am able to configure the dongle by going to 192.168.0.1 in the browser and using the GUI. But I´d like to reach and configure the dongle using the console / bash scripts.
Running lsusb gives me this result:
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM ZTE Mobile Broadband

However, when I run sudo mmcli -L it returns:
No modems were found

The result remains the same even if I turn off the Wi-Fi hotspot of the dongle. The main task would to automate the dongle setup process with a bash script. Anyone knows a way to resolve this issue?

Can you show the output of lsusb.py lsusb.py -ci for the modem? And the output of dmesg -ewL starting with the moment the ZTE dongle is connected?

I cannot show it unfortunatelly as I´m writing from another computer. I can tell you though:
usb-storage 7-1:1-0 USB Mass Storage device detected
shortly followed by:
cdc_ether 7-1:1-0 eth1 register ´cdc_ether´at usb-xhci-hcd.4.auto-1, ZTE CDC Ethernet Device

Most likely, ModemManager cannot find it because of the same reason that allows you to access it via 192.168.0.1 (and which lets the modem provide Wi-Fi).
In this mode, the modem does not look like a modem to the system – it looks like a generic USB Ethernet (CDC or RNDIS) interface, with none of the usual "modem" control interfaces (AT/QMI/MBIM) exposed. In effect, it's like your computer is connected via Ethernet to a standalone router, and only that router's firmware can talk to the actual "modem" chip. The only difference is that the router is stick-shaped.
(I suspect the ZTE stick even runs embedded Linux and probably has the same firmware as their standalone routers do... as this is certainly the case for Huawei LTE sticks.)
I couldn't find anything in Linux's "usb_modeswitch" tool that mentions alternative modes for ZTE modems. It's possible that it might expose them as USB configurations (by writing different values to /sys/bus/usb/devices/7-1/bConfigurationValue), or that it might need a different kind of magic command, or that it just doesn't have an AT/MBIM/QMI pass-through mode at all.

Though, in any case, ModemManager wouldn't configure the modem permanently – it has to be running every time to apply the configuration (like what your modem's internal firmware currently does!) – so maybe it's not what you're looking for anyway.
When the modem is only configurable through HTTP, you still have the option of scripting the actual HTTP requests (basically emulating the browser) – which can be done by watching the browser's DevTools request log to see which clicks cause what requests.
Some people seem to have tried doing so:

https://github.com/paulo-correia/ZTE_API_and_Hack
https://github.com/wijayamin/zte-modem-api-docs

